# Как организована разработка и дальнейшая поддержка шаблонов custom WordPress-темы?

Tags: html, wordpress, webpack, pug

Натягиваю вёрстку на движок WP. Для реализации frontend-части выбрал Webpack (PUG + Sass). На выходе получил исходники, которые "нарезаю" в соответствующие WP-шаблоны. 
Мне не нравится двух-этапный процесс поддержки, когда изменения нужно вносить сначала в статические файлы (вёрстку), а потом - в php-шаблоны. Хочу иметь контроль версий и эффективно менеджерить созданную тему. 
Могу встроить php-теги в pug-шаблоны и настроить их конвертацию в wp-шаблоны, но подход выглядит костыльно. 
Интересно, какие подходы и какой стек технологий используете вы. Спасибо.

Comment: Конечно, костыльно делать бэк из фронта. Создавайте тему в WordPress, пишите её шаблоны в php, используйте шаблонизатор типа twig (хотя и сам php - это шаблонизатор). Применяйте webpack только там, где это нужно. Держите тему под git. Так все работают с WordPress.

Comment: @kaagdesign, Спасибо за ваш ответ!
Сегодня на практике убедился, что интеграция pug и php очень неудобная (отсутствие поддержки IDE + неудобный синтаксис).
Но я ещё не сдался и хочу попробовать частичную конвертацию pug-шаблонов в php-файлы. Так же нашёл этот сет инструментов (настроенные системы
сборки для WP) [ссылка](https://roots.io/). Вы слышали о них \ использовали?
Я правильно вас понял: вы создаёте темы сразу в WP-шаблонах, без предварительного этапа вёрстки?

Comment: Да, о Bedrocks знаю, но не использую. Считаю, что там много лишнего. Но это долгий и отдельный разговор. В разработке использую composer, webpack, phpunit-тесты и ещё ряд инструментов. Можете посмотреть на примере плагина cyr2lat https://github.com/mihdan/cyr2lat.

Comment: Считаю "натягивание" вёрстки на WordPress неправильным подходом. При этом обычно получаются нередактируемые сайты. При вёрстке тем сначала создаю болванку контента в админке (смысловые блоки текста), а потом уже начинаю вешать на них стили и добавлять js.